# Creating Subset of Vector Adds Null Values

Tags: r, vector, mergesort

I'm trying to create a mergeSort algorithm in R. While I *think* I have the method down, the first time I create the vector `e`, I end up with a vector of length 4 instead of 2. This causes the error below:

> > "Error in if (a[2] < a[1]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

For some reason, R is adding an extra 2 elements to what should be a two-element vector. If anyone has an explanation for this, that would be wonderful. (Please limit advice to solving this error. I want to figure out how to do the rest on my own.)

Code:

```
addLeftOver <- function(buffer, array, index) {
  j <- length(buffer)
  for(i in array[index:length(array)]) {
    buffer[j] = i
    print(i)
    j <- j+1
  }
  return(buffer)
}

mergeSort <- function(a) {
  len <- length(a)
  print(a)
  print(len)
  browser()
  if(len<=2) {  #base case
    if(len==1) {
      return(a)
    }
    if(a[2]<a[1]) {
      return(c(a[2],a[1]))
    }
    return(a)
  }
  print(len/2)
  b <- mergeSort(a[1:(len/2)])     #recursion
  e <- mergeSort(a[(len/2)+1:len]) #recursion
  indexB <- 1
  indexE <- 1
  buffer

  for(i in 1:len) {
    if(e[indexC]<b[indexB]) {
      buffer[index] <- e[indexE]
      index <- index + 1
      indexE <- indexE + 1
    } else {
      buffer[index] <- b[indexB]
      index <- index + 1
      indexB <- indexB + 1
    }
    if(indexB==len/2) {
      buffer = addLeftover(buffer, e, indexE)
      return(buffer)
    }
    if(indexE==len/2) {
      buffer = addLeftover(buffer, b, indexB)
      return(buffer)
    }
  }
}

sumArray <- c(6,4,2,7,8,1,3,5)
print(mergeSort(sumArray))
```

The `addLeftOver()` function's purpose is to copy the remnants of one of the two vectors (`b` or `e`) to the buffer when the end of the other has been reached.

Comment: what is the result you want to obtain from the code above?

Comment: All it needs to do is sort a vector of integers 'a'

Comment: so you want to sort a vector, without using the sort function? Is that your aim?

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on developing a Wavelet Transform based codec and I needed to re-acquaint myself with recursive algorithms. That's the main reason I'm trying to reproduce the merge sort algorithm. The code in the answer below should work.

Comment: What is the result you expect to get from `c(1,2,3,5,4)`?

Comment: if you do `print(mergeSort(c(1,2,3,5,4))` it should return `1 2 3 4 5`. Also, how are you doing inline code sections?

Comment: if you are using rmarkdown then you will use \`r value\`

Comment: Thanks, it looks way better now

Comment: Hope you were able to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Main error can be fixed with parenthesis. `e <- mergeSort(a[(len/2)+1:len])` should be 
 `e <- mergeSort(a[((len/2)+1:len])`
That and some other bugs were fixed. 
Working code:

```
addLeftOver <- function(buffer, array, index) 
{
 j <- length(buffer)+1
 for(i in array[index:length(array)]) {
   buffer[j] = i
   j <- j+1
 }
 return(buffer)
}

mergeSort <- function(a)
{
  len <- length(a)
  if(len<=2)
  {
    if(len==1)
    {
      return(a)
    }
    if(a[2]<a[1])
    {
      return(c(a[2],a[1]))
    }
    return(a)
  }
  half <- as.integer(len/2)
  b <- mergeSort(a[1:(half)])
  e <- mergeSort(a[((half)+1):len])
  index <- 1
  indexB <- 1
  indexE <- 1
  buffer <- c(0)

  for(i in 1:len)
  {
    if(e[indexE]<b[indexB])
    {
      buffer[index] <- e[indexE]
      index <- index + 1
      indexE <- indexE + 1
    }
    else
    {
      buffer[index] <- b[indexB]
      index <- index + 1
      indexB <- indexB + 1
    }
    if(indexB==(length(b))+1)
    {
      buffer = addLeftover(buffer, e, indexE)
      return(buffer)
    }
    if(indexE==(length(e))+1)
    {
      buffer = addLeftover(buffer, b, indexB)
      return(buffer)
    }
  }
}
```